# NearQuery Spring Data MongoDB Spatial

Tags: spring, mongodb, geospatial, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data MongoDb and trying to do spatial queries. I dont have a Java object at all. I get a lat/long from the input and then try to find nearby merchants. I used the below code but it did not work.

```
    DBCollection dbCollection = template.getCollection("user");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    Point point = new Point(33.4941704, -111.9260519);
    NearQuery nearQuery = null;
    query.put("loc", nearQuery.near(point).toDBObject());
    System.out.println("Query is : " + query.toString());
    DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);
    System.out.println("Cursor : " + cursor.count());
```

The query that was output was

```
    Query is : { "loc" : { "near" : [ 33.4941704 , -111.9260519] , "spherical" : false}}
```

The cursor did not return any rows.

But when I changed the near to $near using the below code, the cursor gave me expected results.

```
    DBCollection dbCollection = template.getCollection("user");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    Point point = new Point(33.4941704, -111.9260519);
    NearQuery nearQuery = null;
    query.put("loc", nearQuery.near(point).toDBObject());
    String dummyString = query.toString();
    dummyString = dummyString.replace("near", "$near");
    DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find((DBObject) JSON.parse(dummyString));
```

Now the query is

```
    { "loc" : { "$near" : [ 33.4941704 , -111.9260519] , "spherical" : false}}
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug in the Spring NearQuery class?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the `$near` [operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) and the `geoNear` [command](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) in MongoDB. `NearQuery` when, executed through `MongoTemplate`, runs the `geoNear` command.

> The geoNear command provides an alternative to the $near operator. In addition to the functionality of $near, geoNear returns additional diagnostic information.

So you might want to fall back to using `BasicQuery` along with `MongoTemplate`.